# Slow response from Oozie Web Service

Tags: bigdata, analytics, oozie, ambari

I'm actually trying to debug on why is my Oozie responding quite slow when I'm trying to query via the Oozie web services API.

```
GET /oozie/v1/jobs?jobtype=wf&len=500
```

On a good time, I managed to get the response within 4 seconds, but on a bad time, it can reach up to 5 mins to get the response. So, the issue is not always happening.

Also, I have data on Oozie since 2014 (around 640K old data) so I'm not sure if this could be the root cause. Could it be the memory config?

Thanks in advance!

Ref: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WebServicesAPI.html